# Get start time, end time and test duration of JMeter load test

Tags: jmeter

I need to capture StartTime(Format:2021-04-28T12:09:09.000009), EndTime(Format:2021-04-28T12:09:09.000009) and test duration(milliseconds) of a JMeterLoad test.
I planning to capture StartTime(Format:2021-04-28T12:09:09.000009) in SetupThreadGroup in Jsr223Sampler and EndTime(Format:2021-04-28T12:09:09.000009) & duration in tearDownThreadGroup using below code.

---SetupThread

```
def now = new Date()
def starttime = now.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssssss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
vars.put("StartTime", starttime)
```

--- TearDownThreadGroup

```
def now = new Date()
def endtime = now.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssssss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
vars.put("EndTime", endtime)
def diff = vars.get("StartTime")-endtime
```

Getting below error

```
2021-04-28 18:17:11,475 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script GetEndTime_Duration, message: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method minus() on null object
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method minus() on null object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have start time saved already in variable `TESTSTART.MS`, you can use it in script, e.g.

```
long starttime = Long.valueOf(vars.get("TESTSTART.MS"))
def now = new Date()
def endtime = now.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssssss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
vars.put("EndTime", endtime) 
def diff = now.getTime() - starttime
log.info String.valueOf(diff)
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable inputs. is there any way to convert TESTSTART.MS to this format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssssss

Comment: I am able to convert it using below code. thanks for your help   long starttime = Long.valueOf(vars.get("TESTSTART.MS"))
def start_time = new Date(starttime)
def formatter = start_time.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssssss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
log.info "Starttime:----" + formatter

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your script:

1. You're using `vars` shorthand which stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance and according to [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

   > Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function

   so you should be using `props` instead of `vars`, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on what do these shorthands mean
2. You're subtracting 2 strings
3. You're subtracting larger value (end time) from the lower value (start time)

My expectation is that in the setUp Thread Group you should use the following code:

```
def starttime = System.currentTimeMillis()
props.put("StartTime", starttime)
```

and in the tearDown Thread Group:

```
def endtime = System.currentTimeMillis()
def diff = endtime - props.get('StartTime')

log.info('Diff: ' + diff)
```